# Checksum implementation in php web services

Tags: php, json, web-services, checksum

I have php web services for getting huge amount of data in JSON format. Currently i am using count of sending data and received data comparing for success case. Recently i heard method called checksum. How can i implement  checksum in this scenario ?

Comment: *Currently i am using count of sending data and received data comparing for success case.* Whats that mean?

Comment: count of data sent from server will compared with count of json data received in application. But both requires database query.

Comment: Server to server?

Comment: 2 scenarios. one is getting data from one server to another server, and another one is from server to mobile application

Comment: Sign the payload with [hash_hmac](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) and a known key, much like how [JWT](https://jwt.io/) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sign the payload with [hash_hmac()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php), with a known key, the token created would be passed through using HTTP headers.

For example:

```
<?php
// key which will sign the data 
$key = hash('sha256', 'Unique user data or Some secret');

// your data
$array = [
    'foobar' => 'baz'    
];

// encode the payload
$json = json_encode($array);

// sign it with key
$token = hash_hmac('sha256', $json, $key);

// set response header
header('X-Checksum: '.$token);

echo $json;
```

This is how the receiver would verify the received data.

```
// faked: this would be populated by the request/response
$_POST['json'] = $json; 
$_SERVER['X-Checksum'] = $token; 

// verify the data matches token by signing the data with the key
$check = hash_hmac('sha256', $_POST['json'], $key);
if (hash_equals($token, $check)) {
    echo 'Verified';
} else {
    echo 'Tampered';
}

// example tampered data
$_POST['json'] = 'tampered'.$json; 

$check = hash_hmac('sha256', $_POST['json'], $key);
if (hash_equals($token, $check)) {
    echo 'Verified';
} else {
    echo 'Tampered';
}
```

See it online: https://3v4l.org/tvUUR

Comment: Thank you @ Lawrence Cherone